# ImageResizer SimpleFilters VB.net Sample Code

Tags: vb.net, imageresizer

We have been trying to use: ImageResizer and it's SimpleFilters for the image filtering.

There is no VB.net Sample Code. Not in the plugin docs: http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/simplefilters

And amazingly, there is not sample code online, ie Google searches.

We have tried:

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(original, newImage, New ResizeSettings("width=100&height=200&crop=auto&s.grayscale=true"));
```

Then:

```
Dim instr As New ImageResizer.Instructions()
With instr
    .Grayscale = True
End With
```

And Finally:

```
Dim resizer As New ImageResizer.ImageJob(bmpImg, fileLocation, New ImageResizer.ResizeSettings("width=2000;height=2000;format=jpg;s.grayscale=true;mode=max"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement all plugins for ImageResizer like this:

```
Dim conf As New ImageResizer.Configuration.Config()

Call (New SimpleFilters()).Install(conf)

conf.BuildImage(Source_Image, Converted_Image, "width=2000;height=2000;format=jpg;s.grayscale=true;mode=max")
```